Match Topology nodes
Hi everybody I was wondering if there is any documentation on how to setup something like the Match topology node in Houdini.
I know the sort elements was node was intended for that but I wonder how I could use that in combination with the topology nodes to sort vertices idx sampling the topology of another mesh based on a face selection?
https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/nodes/sop/matchtopology.html#parameters
Thank you very much in advance

If both geometries are the same but have different indices, you could actually just use the node Sample Nearest and Sample Index. With Sample Nearest you get the nearest point of the second geometry, and with Sample Index you get the index of this geometry. It would look something like this: https://i.sstatic.net/HSp5gxOy.png

What is this Match Topology node you mention and what does it do? Not everyone here is a Houdini user, nor necessarily knows what that does. Could you rephrase your question and explain what you expect to achieve, and also describe with words what that feature does? Ideally in a way that doesn't reference other software so that someone who never used it but knows blender could answer your question? Maybe add a few reference images? or GIF of the desired results

But simple nearest would not actually find a topological match it will match by closest element which is not what I want. What I want the node network to do is matching the indices starting by a 3 points selection on each mesh and find the connected edges starting from there.
There is actually an add on that is doing that.
https://bartoszstyperek.gumroad.com/l/copy_verts_ids
Problem is that python is not really efficient when it comes to iterating a large number of vertices. That's why I was thinking of using a geometry node solution.
